# Bootstrap Modal Form Switch - One Click Function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

So I've looked around stackoverflow before posting this question, but didn't find a solid answer, so I'm posting this. I'm not asking how to switch forms using bootstrap as I have already accomplished that here - http://cdpn.io/luotA

What my questions is how I can simplify my jquery selectors to be one function. What I'm having to do now for this to work is to call each click out separately for each button to make the switch happen. Please see pen http://cdpn.io/luotA - click on edit pen on the lower left to fork and make changes

What I want is one simple click function to accomplish the same thing. Any suggestions and or answers would be great. You can fork pen and post back url for working examples.

Thanks in advance.

Here is the code:

```
              $("#join-trigger").click(function(){
               $('#modal-login').modal('hide');
               $('#modal-join').modal('show');
              });

              $("#forgot-trigger").click(function(){
                $('#modal-login').modal('hide');
                $('#modal-forgot').modal('show');
              });

              $("#login-trigger").click(function(){
                $('#modal-join').modal('hide');
                $('#modal-login').modal('show');
              });

              $("#back-login").click(function(){
                $('#modal-forgot').modal('hide');
                $('#modal-login').modal('show');
              });

              $("#back-join").click(function(){
                $('#modal-forgot').modal('hide');
                $('#modal-join').modal('show');
              });
```

Comment: Could you please post the relevant code?

Comment: Just posted the code - looking to simplify this into one function to make more efficient -Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a quick thing I wrote:

```
$("#join-trigger, #forgot-trigger, #login-trigger, #back-login, #back-join").click(function(){
  var hash = {
    'join-trigger': ['modal-login', 'modal-join'],
    'forgot-trigger': ['modal-login', 'modal-forgot'],
    'login-trigger': ['modal-join', 'modal-login'],
    'back-login': ['modal-forgot', 'modal-login'],
    'back-join': ['modal-forgot', 'modal-join']
  };

  $('#' + hash[$(this).attr('id')][0]).modal('hide');
  $('#' + hash[$(this).attr('id')][1]).modal('show');
});
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/kECDA

Comment: This is great. A smart way to go about it, what I was looking for. Thanks for sending back link to share working example.